ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on Vercel Deployment with Next.js Middleware
I want to add subdomain functionality in my Next.js project. I have multiple stores available in my database, and I'm fetching store data based on the subdomain. I want the URL structure to be in the form of subdomain.mydomain.com/theme.
I’m encountering an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with my Next.js application deployed on Vercel. The issue arises when accessing URLs with a custom subdomain. Everything works perfectly on localhost, but the problem occurs when the app is deployed. Here’s the relevant middleware code and details about the issue:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

interface StoreData {
  selectedTheme: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = request.nextUrl;
  const hostname = request.headers.get("host") || "";
  const subdomain = hostname.split(".")[0];

  // Check if it's an admin route
  const isAdminRoute = url.pathname.startsWith("/admin");

  if (
    !isAdminRoute &&
    subdomain !== "www" &&
    subdomain !== "sinpshop-git-dev-mohsin-mohsin-hassans-projects" &&
    subdomain !== "localhost" &&
    subdomain !== "sinpshop"
  ) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/v1/stores/get-store-info/${subdomain}`
      );
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const data: StoreData = await res.json();

      if (data && data.selectedTheme) {
        let path: string;
        switch (data.selectedTheme) {
          case "theme_1":
            path = `/${subdomain}/sinp-shop`;
            break;
          case "theme_2":
            path = `/${subdomain}/ekko`;
            break;
          case "theme_3":
            path = `/${subdomain}/elink`;
            break;
          default:
            path = "/admin/login";
        }

        if (url.pathname === "/") {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(path, request.url));
        }

        // Rewrite the URL to include the subdomain info
        const newUrl = new URL(url.pathname, request.url);
        newUrl.searchParams.set("storeData", JSON.stringify(data));
        return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching store info:", error);
      // Redirect to admin login page if there's an error
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/login", request.url));
    }
  }

  // Handle admin routes
  if (isAdminRoute) {
    const token = request.cookies.get("accessToken");
    const isLoginPage = url.pathname === "/admin/login";

    if (isLoginPage && token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/dashboard", request.url));
    }

    if (!isLoginPage && !token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/login", request.url));
    }
  }

  // For all other requests, continue normally
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
    "/admin/:path*",
  ],
};

Code:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

interface StoreData {
  selectedTheme: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = request.nextUrl;
  const hostname = request.headers.get("host") || "";
  const subdomain = hostname.split(".")[0];

  // Check if it's an admin route
  const isAdminRoute = url.pathname.startsWith("/admin");

  if (
    !isAdminRoute &&
    subdomain !== "www" &&
    subdomain !== "sinpshop-git-dev-mohsin-mohsin-hassans-projects" &&
    subdomain !== "localhost" &&
    subdomain !== "sinpshop"
  ) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/v1/stores/get-store-info/${subdomain}`
      );
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const data: StoreData = await res.json();

      if (data && data.selectedTheme) {
        let path: string;
        switch (data.selectedTheme) {
          case "theme_1":
            path = `/${subdomain}/sinp-shop`;
            break;
          case "theme_2":
            path = `/${subdomain}/ekko`;
            break;
          case "theme_3":
            path = `/${subdomain}/elink`;
            break;
          default:
            path = "/admin/login";
        }

        if (url.pathname === "/") {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(path, request.url));
        }

        // Rewrite the URL to include the subdomain info
        const newUrl = new URL(url.pathname, request.url);
        newUrl.searchParams.set("storeData", JSON.stringify(data));
        return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching store info:", error);
      // Redirect to admin login page if there's an error
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/login", request.url));
    }
  }

  // Handle admin routes
  if (isAdminRoute) {
    const token = request.cookies.get("accessToken");
    const isLoginPage = url.pathname === "/admin/login";

    if (isLoginPage && token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/dashboard", request.url));
    }

    if (!isLoginPage && !token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/login", request.url));
    }
  }

  // For all other requests, continue normally
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
    "/admin/:path*",
  ],
};


What I Tried and Expected:

Verified Environment Variables: Ensured that NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL is correctly set in Vercel. I expected the base URL to correctly resolve the API requests without errors.

Checked SSL Configuration: Confirmed that Vercel handles SSL for custom domains properly. I expected the SSL certificate to be correctly issued and valid for the custom subdomain, avoiding any SSL errors.

Debugged Middleware: Added additional logging in the middleware to trace issues with URL handling and subdomain processing. I expected to identify any issues with URL rewriting or fetch requests that might cause SSL errors.


Actual Result:
Instead of the application functioning correctly with the expected URL redirections and rewrites, I encountered an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing the Vercel-deployed URL with a custom subdomain. The error indicates that the SSL configuration might be incorrect or that there’s an issue with how the request is being handled.
I want the url work as same as it work on localhost:3000.
when hit this url:
http://dukaaaaaaan.localhost:3000/
it redirect me to the related store and the active theme:
http://dukaaaaaaan.localhost:3000/dukaaaaaaan/sinp-shop
but when deploy the code on vercel and try like this:
https://dukaaaaaaan.sinpshop-a7zu49k6n-mohsin-hassans-projects.vercel.app/

Vercel link image description 

What is the value of NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL?
